# How to know whether an std::string is of correct coding?

Tags: c++, string, stl

In my program, I get an `std::string` value from another function which read strings from different sources, the string here always contains non-ASCII characters.

I am debugging the program with Visual Studio. Sometimes when the string content **looks correct in VS debugger**, then the next step is okay(for example use this string as a directory of input and output). But sometimes the string content **looks incorrect**, this cause the next step went wrong.

Currently I use `QString` as a bridge to convert "incorect" string to "correct" string, code like below.

```
// get string from somewhere else, sometimes correct sometimes incorrect
string str = getString(); 
QString strQ = QString::fromStdString(str);
str = string(strQ.toLocal8bit);
```

But sometimes the str is "correct" already before converting, in that case if I convert it with the code above, it went wrong.

So I suppose here the problem is how can I know whether an `std::string` have correct encoding? Because I can't always judge it by eyes.

Yes, coding is a widely discussed topic on Stack Overflow, but I still cannot find an appropriate solution.

**P.S.** 
correct string value looks like `孙夏^4735` in VS debugger, incorrect string value looks like `????`。

Comment: A `std::string` has no concept of encoding. It contains `char`s with some values. Encoding depends on whatever interprets those values.

Comment: Strings are just bytes under the hood. How those bytes are interpreted depends on which encoding scheme you select. If you have non-ASCII characters, when you go to decode the string (like displaying it to console or into a file), make sure you're decoding in unicode, or UTF-8, or whatever encoding scheme you used when you roped in the data. There is no "correct" and "incorrect" encoding schemes, they are just different.

Comment: Usually, when you pass text to an application you either use the correct encoding the application is expecting or there is some way to tell the application which encoding the text you are providing is in.  If you are reading strings from different sources then maybe you need a way (configuration file?) to tell your program which sources provide which encodings?

Comment: You need to go back to the source of the issue identified in your 1st paragraph.  This _"...another function..."_ should be changed to either (a) standardise the encoding of the returned string or (b) also return the encoding of the returned string.  My preference is (a).

Comment: Thank you, do you mean like that VS debugger use a certain interprets to show string, so sometimes when the string is originally stored with that kind of interprets rules, it looks right, otherwise it looks wrong.

Comment: Trying to "guess" the encoding of character data (UTF-8, UTF-16, MBCS pick a code page, etc) is not possible in the general case.  You can make an educated guess if you know the likely locale but even then it's still only a guess.  Have a read of this for some background: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093

Comment: Yes, debuggers are awesome but which character encoding a string of bytes might be from cannot be known to them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check if the string is already UTF-8 encoded. Something like the following code (never tested, use it for you inspiration).

```
#include <string>

enum DetectedCoding {ASCII, UTF8, OTHER};

DetectedCoding DetectEncoding(const std::string & s)
{
  const char * cs = s.c_str();
  DetectedCoding d = ASCII;
  while (*cs)
  {
    unsigned char b = (unsigned char)*(cs++);
    if (b & 0x80) { // not a plain ASCII character
      // if the string is already UTF8 encoded, then it must conform to a multibyte sequence standard. Let's verify it
      if (b < 0xC0) // first of all, b must start with 11
        return OTHER; //  no multibyte sequence starts with 10xxxxxx
      // now we expect a number of continuation bytes, depending on the number of ones following the 11
      size_t nCont = 0;
      if (b < 0xE0) // two bytes sequence: 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
        nCont = 1;
      else if (b < 0xF0) // three bytes sequence: 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        nCont = 2;
      else if (b < 0xF8) // four bytes sequence: 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        nCont = 3;
      else if (b < 0xFC) // five bytes sequence: 111110xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        nCont = 4;
      else if (b < 0xFE) // six bytes sequence: 1111110x 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
        nCont = 5;
      else
        return OTHER; //  no multibyte sequence starts with 1111111x
      while (nCont--)
        if (((unsigned char)*(cs++) & 0xC0) != 0xC0) // in case string ends, 0 is found so the following test prevents us from illegal memory access
          return OTHER; //  each continuation byte must starts with 10xxxxxx
      d = UTF8;
    }
  }
  return d;
}
```

Comment: Note that this *can* misclassify other text as utf8, but *can't* misclassify utf8 or ascii.

Comment: This also can misclassify UTF-8 as ASCII. (While you probably understand why and accept the interpretation required, others might not.)